# Angular inheritance Can't resolve all parameters

Tags: angular, super

I am trying to extend my `BaseComponent` in `ChildComponent`.
Constructor in `ChildComponent` looks like this:

```
    import { DATA_POST_PAYLOAD_ID} from './constants';
                 // ...
      @Component({
        selector: 'app-child',
        templateUrl: './child.component.html',
        styleUrls: [
          './child.component.scss',
          '../path/to/another/file.scss'
        ]
      })
       // ...
                 constructor(protected dataService: dataService,
                              protected spinnerService: LoadingSpinnerServicesService,
                              protected detailPayloadService: DetailReqPayloadService) {
                    super({
                      dataService: dataService,
                      POST_PAYLOAD_ID: DATA_POST_PAYLOAD_ID,
                      spinnerService: spinnerService,
                      detailPayloadService: detailPayloadService
                    });
                  }
```

And my `BaseComponent` constructor looks like this:

```
          @Component({
            selector: 'app-base',
            templateUrl: './base.component.html',
            styleUrls: ['./base.component.scss']
          })

     export class BaseContentComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
            // ...
      constructor(protected opts: BaseDetailContentOpts) {
      }
```

BaseDetailContentOpts:

```
export interface BaseDetailContentOpts {
  dataService: any;
  POST_PAYLOAD_ID: string;
  spinnerService: LoadingSpinnerServicesService,
  detailPayloadService: DetailReqPayloadService
}
```

In browser console I am getting an error:

```
compiler.js:466 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for BaseComponent: (?).
at syntaxError (compiler.js:466)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:15547)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js:15382)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (compiler.js:14890)
at CompileMetadataResolver.loadDirectiveMetadata (compiler.js:14745)
at eval (compiler.js:33508)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at eval (compiler.js:33507)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:33504)
```

Comment: what about DATA_POST_PAYLOAD_ID?

Comment: It is from import ... updated

Comment: would you share live example (for example [here](https://stackblitz.com/)). Just a basic code which reproduce the issue? Also how your BaseComponent is decorated? (with @Injectable() or with @Component())

Comment: please update the full code. are you using any inheritance?

Comment: I updated my post

Comment: You can't use interface as token for provider

Comment: Also inheritance of the @Component() decorators will not work. One possible solution is to remove @Component() decorator from BaseContentComponent and inherit it just as a class, this will prevent the injector to try to resolve the BaseContentComponent constructor properties and you will be responsible to correctly pass the parameters (you already do with super() call in ChildComponent). Please note that you will need to call ngOnInit and ngOnDestroy of BaseContentComponent from your child component manually.

Comment: @NikolaYankov this means that i cannot use OnInit, OnDestroy in BaseClass ?

Comment: @TomP You can't use the automated invocation, but you can call them from ChildComponent ngOnInit and ngOnDestroy handlers with super.ngOnInit() and super.ngOnDestroy().

Comment: @NikolaYankov I deleted component decorator from base class and also deleted base class from app.module.ts. And it is working. Also I did not had to call super.ngOnInit. Automated invocation is working.